# TSQL - parsing XML variable while maintaining XML structure

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have a procedure with an XML parameter that I need to be able to split up by the node 'Document' while retaining the XML formatting so I can insert each 'Document' node into a table. I have tried throwing everything into a temp table and using for xml to parse, but that didn't work.  This example only has two 'Document' nodes, but there can be any number.
Here is the XML structure:

```
DECLARE @XMLVariable xml
SET     @XMLVariable = '<Documents>
  <Document>
    <UncFilePath>\\server\file1.PDF</UncFilePath>
    <Pages>
      <Page>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <IsValidFlg>1</IsValidFlg>
      </Page>
      <Page>
        <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
        <IsValidFlg>0</IsValidFlg>
      </Page>
    </Pages>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <UncFilePath>\\server\file2.PDF</UncFilePath>
    <Pages>
      <Page>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <IsValidFlg>1</IsValidFlg>
      </Page>
      <Page>
        <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
        <IsValidFlg>0</IsValidFlg>
      </Page>
    </Pages>
  </Document>
</Documents>'
```

The final result would be two rows containing the actuall XML of (and including) each 'Document' node:

Row 1 xml column:

```
        <Document>
    <UncFilePath>\\server\file1.PDF</UncFilePath>
    <Pages>
      <Page>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <IsValidFlg>1</IsValidFlg>
      </Page>
      <Page>
        <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
        <IsValidFlg>0</IsValidFlg>
      </Page>
    </Pages>
  </Document>
```

Row 2 xml column:

```
        <Document>
    <UncFilePath>\\server\file2.PDF</UncFilePath>
    <Pages>
      <Page>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <IsValidFlg>1</IsValidFlg>
      </Page>
      <Page>
        <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
        <IsValidFlg>0</IsValidFlg>
      </Page>
    </Pages>
  </Document>
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  Figured it out.

SELECT pref.query('.') as Document
FROM   @XMLVariable.nodes('/*/*') AS T(pref)